# Using Single JQuery File For Multiple Pages Causing 'Uncaught TypeError'

Tags: jquery

In my project each app has a single `static` file containing that app's JQuery.

I get the following error printed to console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
```

I understand why I am getting this error, it's saying that it cannot find the element on the page. This is because I have this one JQuery file for multiple webpages and each contain different elements.

I know I could just create a different JQuery file for every webpage, but this doesn't seem right. I feel I should be able to have a single JQuery file per app.

How can I have a single JQuery file which is used by multiple webpages, each of which contain different elements, without having this error thrown?

--Edit--

This is a single JQuery file:

```
# this exists on webpage A
var example1 = document.getElementById("example1_fields");
    if (document.getElementById("id_example1").checked == false) {
        example1_questions.style.display = "none";
    }
# this exists on webpage B
    var example2 = document.getElementById("example2_fields");
    if (document.getElementById("id_example2").checked == false) {
        example2_questions.style.display = "none";
    }
```

I get the `Uncaught TypeError` thrown on page A because it can't find `div_id_two` and I get the same error on page B because it can't find `div_id_one`.

Thank you.

Comment: You're asking an X/Y question. Using a single JS file for all pages is correct. You simply need to diagnose this error and fix it. Double click the error in the console and it will take you to the line of code that caused it. Whatever variable you're trying to get `checked` from is null. Without seeing the relevant code, we cannot help further than that

Comment: I edited my question to include more information. I don't think there is a problem to diagnose, my issue (I think) is that this error is being thrown on every page because the file contains code referring to elements which don't exist on every page

Comment: The code you've shown is not relevant to the error. Did you try double clicking it in the console to see where the cause is?

Comment: Sorry, it's the code that executes on doc load that's causing the problems. I updated my question

Comment: Thanks for the update, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're retrieving the `checked` property of elements which only exist on some pages and not others. You simply need to add a check that the element exists before you work with it:

```js
// this exists on webpage A
var example1 = document.getElementById("example1_fields");
var id_example1 = document.getElementById("id_example1");
if (id_example1 && id_example1.checked == false) {
  example1_questions.style.display = "none";
}

// this exists on webpage B
var example2 = document.getElementById("example2_fields");
var id_example2 = document.getElementById("id_example2");
if (id_example2 && id_example2.checked == false) {
  example2_questions.style.display = "none";
}
```

However it's worth noting that using classes and looping through all the elements which exist is a much better approach. Not least because it avoids the need for the above check, but it's also more extensible and easier to maintain.

Using your current pattern, if you add an `id_example3` element in future you would need to amend the JS as well. In the below jQuery example you can have an (theoretically) infinite number of elements in the HTML without needing to change the JS:

```js
$('.example').on('change', function() {
  $(this).next('.questions').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```css
.questions {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" /> Foo
<div class="questions">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="example" /> Bar
<div class="questions">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but this is not even jQuery but vanilla javascript. Anyhow, you should check that these things you are searching from the document actually exist:

```
# this exists on webpage A
var example1 = document.getElementById("example1_fields");
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("id_example1");
if (checkbox1 !== null && example1 !== null && checkbox1.checked === false) {
    example1_questions.style.display = "none";
}

# this exists on webpage B
var example2 = document.getElementById("example2_fields");
var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("id_example2");
if (checkbox2 !== null && example2 !== null && checkbox2.checked === false) {
    example2_questions.style.display = "none";
}
```